# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error during performSegueWithIdentifier, using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

I'm new to iOS development and I'm implementing a slide-out menu, using the well-known SWRevealViewController by John Lluch. I'm following this video tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SUV1YY2yxQ

So far I have this storyboard:

[image]

The initial scene (Reveal View Controller) is trying to automatically trigger the 1st two segues (to the Table View and Navigation Controller).

When I build the app, I get the following error:

[SWRevealViewController initWithIdentifier:source:destination:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d96f000

This error occurs on the line I've indicated below, in the 'loadStoryboardControllers' method, in SWRevealViewController.m (which is the class of my initial 'RevealViewController' scene on the storyboard)

```
- (void)loadStoryboardControllers
{
    if ( self.storyboard && _rearViewController == nil )
    {
        //Try each segue separately so it doesn't break prematurely if either Rear or Right views are not used.
        @try
        {
            //**ERROR OCCURS ON FOLLOWING LINE**
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SWSegueRearIdentifier sender:nil];
        }
        @catch(NSException *exception) {}

        @try
        {
            //**ANOTHER ALMOST IDENTICAL ERROR OCCURS ON FOLLOWING LINE**
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SWSegueFrontIdentifier sender:nil];
        }
        @catch(NSException *exception) {}

        @try
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SWSegueRightIdentifier sender:nil];
        }
        @catch(NSException *exception) {}
    }
}
```

When the error occurs, the value of 'SWSegueRearIdentifier' is @"sw_rear", which is correct. This is the identifier I've given to the segue. The way that the SWRevealViewController is meant to work is that it looks first for the segue identified as "sw_rear" in order to automatically trigger it.

What could be causing the error, or what could I do to debug further?

Comment: Where is the method `initWithIdentifier:source:destination:` invoked?  Basically the exception is saying that the `SWRevealViewController` class doesn't implement that method

Comment: And I have to say that the try/catch code is pretty ugly.  Better just to invoke the segues that you know you will have

Comment: I have an initWithIdentifier method defined within a completely different class that's used for performing segues between different storyboards. What I'm doing in the first instance is seguing to my storyboard via a loading screen, however when I debug, the initWithIdentifier method doesn't seem to be called, and I don't see why that would be invoked anyway at the point where I'm getting the error?

Comment: You need to look at the stack trace when the exception is thrown and work out what called that method.  Somewhere your code thinks it should be dealing with a different object class but actually has `SWRevealViewController`

Comment: Actually the other class that contains initWithIdentifier isn't being called at all, as I'm directly transitioning to my storyboard from the loading page.

Comment: It's not that that class is being called, it is that some other code, which is executing *thinks* it is calling that class, which is why you get an unrecognised selector

Comment: OK thanks. Any idea why the code would think it's calling the other class? The class of both my view controller and segue have nothing to do with that other class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91671/discussion-between-paulw11-and-izzy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initWithIdentifier:source:destination:` is a method implemented by the `UIStoryboardSegue` class.  It is invoked during the segue operation.

In this case it is being invoked against a `UIViewController` subclass, resulting in the exception.

In InterfaceBuilder make sure that the customclass for the Segue is a valid `UIStoryboardSegue` subclass - in the case of SWRevealController it should be `SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController`