# View Controller not transitioning to next view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, segue

I'm building a Quiz App and at the end of the quiz, upon clicking an answer, I want the screen to transition to the ResultViewController where the user's score is displayed. I linked a segue from my MCViewController to the new ResultViewController screen. But upon finishing the quiz, the screen just kinda goes dim, no errors.

MCViewController:

```
 import UIKit

class MCViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var aButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var cButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var dButton: UIButton!

let quiz =
[
    Questions(q: "When did English settlement begin in Canada?", a: "1510", b: "1497", c: "1604", d: "1720", answer: "1604"),
    Questions(q: "Who passed the Quebec Act of 1774?", a: "Canadian Parliament", b: "British Parliament", c: "Quebec Parliament", d: "The French majority", answer: "British Parliament"),
    Questions(q: "Whose portrait is on the Canadian 10 dollar bill?", a: "Sir George Cartier", b: "Sir Etienne Tache", c: "Sir John A. Macdonald", d: "Sir Louis La Fontaine", answer: "Sir John A. Macdonald"),
    Questions(q: "What are the responsibilities of the federal government?", a: "Matters of national and international concern.", b:  "Matters of national concern.", c: "Matters of international concern.", d: "Matters of provincial concern.", answer: " Matters of national and international concern."),
    Questions(q: "What is 'Habeas corpus'?", a: "The right to challenge unlawful detention by the state.", b: "The right to live and work anywhere in Canada.", c: "The right to speak freely.", d: " The right for peaceful assembly.", answer: "The right to challenge unlawful detention by the state.")
]

var questionNumber = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   updateUI()
}

@IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    let userAnswer = sender.currentTitle
    let actualAnswer = quiz[questionNumber].answer
    
    if (userAnswer == actualAnswer) {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red   //END OF ARRAY, SHOULD TRANSITION TO RESULTVIEWCONTROLLER
    }
    
    if (questionNumber + 1 < quiz.count){
        questionNumber += 1
    } else {
        let resultVC = ResultViewController()
        self.present(resultVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
  }

   @objc func updateUI() {
    questionLabel.text = quiz[questionNumber].q
    aButton.setTitle(quiz[questionNumber].a, for: .normal)
    bButton.setTitle(quiz[questionNumber].b, for: .normal)
    cButton.setTitle(quiz[questionNumber].c, for: .normal)
    dButton.setTitle(quiz[questionNumber].d, for: .normal)
    aButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    bButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    cButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    dButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    aButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    bButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    dButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    progressBar.progress = Float(questionNumber + 1) / Float(quiz.count)
}
}
```

ResultViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ResultViewController : UIViewController{
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```

Here's a little bit of my picture if it helps:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code...

```
let resultVC = ResultViewController()
self.present(resultVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

presents a `ResultViewController` that is created using the `init` initialiser, *not from the storyboard*. It is likely the case that you haven't written anything in `ResultViewController.init`, because you did everything in the storyboard, so it does nothing and shows a blank view.

Since you have a segue, you should perform that segue instead!

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "MCResult", sender: nil)
```

You probably have some data that you want to pass to `ResultViewController`. Do that in `prepare(for:)`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ResultViewController {
        // pass whatever you need to "vc"
    }
}
```

Comment: I just put a label there with some text in the ResultViewController and I used the performSegue line instead, now I get this error: Thread 1: "-[Quizzler_iOS13.ResultViewController initWithIdentifier:source:destination:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdc1920f6c0"

Comment: @user13205785 I just realised you set the segue's class to `ResultViewController`... You should not do that. You can just leave that textfield blank. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003481/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error-during-performseguewithidentifier) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You are in same storyBoard so, instantiate your viewController like

```swift
let resultVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultViewControllerID") as! ResultViewController
self.present(resultVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am hoping, you are aware of the UIViewController storyboard ID

Comment: Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099447/sending-data-from-one-uiviewcontroller-to-another-navigationcontroller-using-pre) for passing data